# How to handle high frequency intraday table and then store data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to SQL, and I am currently designing a DB for a project. In this project, there are high-frequency queries intraday but the queries for past days occur at lower frequencies. To decrease the response time for high-frequency queries, the approach I thought about was to create two separate tables, one for intraday and the second one as an archive. At the end of each day, I would copy all the data from the intraday table to the archive table.

Is there a better or standard approach for this task? I have been searching about this and I feel that I don't know the exact term to search for.

Comment: Hi - is your concern that a single query, in isolation, will not run fast enough or is it that you think the volume of concurrent queries will slow the system response down?

Comment: Hello, actually both of them. I thought that separating those tables can help to reduce the response time of those high-frequency queries.

Comment: Not if the high-frequency queries are all still hitting the same (intra-day) table. Tuning your queries, and designing the database structure they run against, is always a good starting point but in the end the solution is probably to specify your environment for the workloads it needs to support